# how to turn off empty value approximation for Telerik chart controls

Tags: telerik, radchart

I am using the Telerik rad chart control to create a bar chart of date-based data. The x-axis shows the date for each data point. The y-axis shows some total.

When there is no data in my datasource for a particular date, the chart is still showing a date, but no bar.

I think this falls under the "empty series approximation" functionality. Is there any way of turning this off? Some property or combination of properties that need to be set?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is using xcategories instead of xvalues in your SeriesMapping. Check the sample:

```
  <TelerikChart:SeriesMapping.ItemMappings>
         <telerik:ItemMapping FieldName="Value" DataPointMember="YValue" />
         <telerik:ItemMapping FieldName="Date" DataPointMember="XCategory" />
   </TelerikChart:SeriesMapping.ItemMappings>
```

I hope it helps.